# ignore xml attribute oreding with soap request in Karate framework

Tags: xml, soap, attributes, karate

I do an XML request: a few tags have attributes which are validated against the schema. As Karate re-orders alphabetically it causes validation errors because the way it was implemented. Any solution to ignore re-ordering of xml attributes when building an XML request?

```
original request = <doc_attr attr_name="1234" attr_value="123">
```

when submitted via karate it's returning as:

```
<doc_attr_value="123" attr attr_name="1234">
```

it got reordered alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine as per the XML specification, so you need to fix your app or change your validation (if it is Karate) for doing a `contains only` type of `match`.

Please see this for more details: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/556#issuecomment-429574161

You are of course welcome to contribute a fix for this because Karate is open-source.

Comment: thank you,changing these legacy application behavior are not feasible. Any suggestion concatenating around multiple request/ variables. OR something like longchar as suggested in the article, may be irrelevant for this https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000034225